# Applying a ternary operator and single const

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this piece of code and I want to minimize the repetition of lines of code we see.

```
 function DummyFunction(){
            const URL_test = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
             const p1 = URL_test.get('Source_ID');
             const p2 = URL_test.get('SourceID');

                if(p1 != null && p1 != undefined){
                    $('input[name=Source_ID]').val(p1)
                    $('input[name=SourceID]').val(p1)
                }else if(p2 != null && p2 != undefined){
                    $('input[name=Source_ID]').val(p2)
                    $('input[name=SourceID]').val(p2)
                }
    }
```

By using one const like

```
const myP = a || b
```

and also using a ternary operator to only have one if statement in the conditions.

Any other opinions for simplification and minimalization of this function?

Answer (score 1):

Put the value to set in a variable first with the conditional operator, then use `.val` with both inputs.

```
const p1 = URL_test.get('Source_ID');
const p2 = URL_test.get('SourceID');

const valToSet = [p1, p2].find(v => v != null && v != undefined);
if (valToSet !== undefined) {
  $('input[name=Source_ID]').val(valToSet);
  $('input[name=SourceID]').val(valToSet);
}
```

Comment: is "v" an unused parameter?

Comment: It's the `.find` parameter - you compare each element in `[p1, p2]` with it

Answer (score 1):

```js
function DummyFunction() {
  const URL_test = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

  const val = URL_test.get('Source_ID') || URL_test.get('SourceID'); //here if there is nothing in the url it will set null.

  console.log(val);

  !!val && $('input[name=Source_ID], input[name=SourceID]').val(val);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="SourceID" />
<input type="text" name="Source_ID" />
```

May be you can use this,

Comment: default value is needed?

Comment: if you don't want to set anything then you can just leave it blank.

Comment: i will change the first function if you don't need the default value that will skip the step

Comment: This will not work if either `.get`s return a falsey but not null/undefined value, like 0 or the empty string. You also shouldn't abuse `&&` as a substitute for the much more readable `if`